# How to display different templates based on condition in angular

Tags: angular

I am doing project in angular. In ts file I am getting array of string value. I may get 3 types string, based on condition.And at a time I will get only one string value in array. That may be 'First'or 'Second' or 'Third'.If I will get 'First' means I need to show different template, Second or third means different different template I need to display. I am not getting how to apply this condition on html file. Any help plz!!!

Comment: [RTFD](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#conditional-display-with-ngif)

Comment: use `*ngIf` or `[ng-switch]` to achieve this. https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition1">Condition 1 stuff</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="condition2">Condition 2 stuff</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="condition3">Condition 3 stuff</ng-container>
```